# How to return the selected tab item's control in the container

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I had a old windows form `WebBrowser` and I had:

```
public WebBrowser getCurrentWebBrowser()  
{  
    return (WebBrowser)TabControl.SelectedTab.Controls[0];
}
```

I want to know how to do the same thing in WPF.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook the TabContols' SelectionChanged event and then have code like this in the callback...

```
  private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            HeaderedContentControl hcc = e.AddedItems[0] as HeaderedContentControl;
            if (hcc != null)
            {
                WebBrowser webBrowser = hcc.Content as WebBrowser;
                if (webBrowser != null)
                {
                    // do something...
                }
            }
        }
```

If you have a WebBrowser in more than one tab, you can name the TabItems and adapt your callback thusly...

```
        <TabItem Header="Browser" Name="MyBrowserTabItem">
            <WebBrowser/>
        </TabItem>


private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    HeaderedContentControl hcc = e.AddedItems[0] as HeaderedContentControl;
    if (hcc != null && hcc.Name == "MyBrowserTabItem")
    {
        WebBrowser webBrowser = hcc.Content as WebBrowser;
        if (webBrowser != null)
        {
            // do something...
        }
    }
}
```

The 'AddedItems' property of the SelectionChangedEventArgs is a list of objects that have been selected since the last time the event was fired.  For a TabControl, AddedItems should normally have a length of 1, and the single element should be an instance of HeaderedContentControl (i.e., the TabItem).